# Python static method wrapper is unnecessary?

Tags: python, class, object, static, static-methods

So I've known about static methods for a while in python and I knew you could use the @staticmethod wrapper but do you really need it if your function has at least one argument? I believe it is likely much better practice but what does it actually do? Because if you write a function with the wrapper and then remove the wrapper it still functions exactly the same. I don't think this is intentional I believe it has to do with how instance functions expect self as the first argument and python by default will pass the instance as first argument. If you have at least one argument you pass the function though it appears you don't even need the wrapper so is the wrapper just for when you have no arguments? (I would never actually use this if I make a static method I would use the wrapper for anyone reading the code's sanity just curious though) Here's an example that I would've thought would error, but it doesn't.

```
class Me:
    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
class Bot1:
    def presentPerson(me):
        print(
            f"Your name is {me.name} and you are {str(me.age)}. You weigh {str(me.weight)} and is about {str(me.height)} feet tall.")
MySelf = Me("Hoax", 16, 50, 5.5)
Bot1.presentPerson(MySelf)
```

Comment: when you don't want object to be created just to use a function defined in that class, that can be a use.

Comment: @Vicrobot Ik that's a use, but if you look at the code I attached, I did the exact same thing, I didn't make an instance and I still called the function directly from the class name without using the staticmethod wrapper

Comment: staticmethod can be used with objects too(in which it ignores the instance argument), so that can be a profit point when you're dealing with objects.